# ValueError: Set gpio mode failed, ... Gpios on BBB

Tags: beagleboneblack, gpio, valueerror, adafruit

I want to manipulate my gpios on Beaglebone black... 
Example:

```
GPIO.setup("P8_11", GPIO.IN)
```

it gives back  the error mentioned in the title:

```
ValueError: Set gpio mode failed, missing file or invalid permissions.
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a problem with u-boot on the BBB. The following hack worked for me:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk1 bs=1M count=100
```

Run that on the BBB, then do a hard reset. This solution came from [this GitHub](https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/issues/165#issuecomment-331565684) issue.

Comment: You're gonna ruin your system that way.
If you want to erase u-boot, you should write zeros only in the first 1...4Mb (depending on BBB release/batch) ― just before the first partition. So, even if you envision this as the only solution (which is false), you should warn people about the sub sequences.

Comment: Fair enough. Like I said, it worked for me but as always it's do at your own risk.